# Turn on and off Webcam with Twillio

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, twilio, webcam

I'm coding a game using Twillio video chat and I've a working first version of it where I can disable and enable audio and video tracks.
But, at the moment, on every laptop we tried it, the green light status of webcam remains active whatever we do.

I found how to disable the light with track.stop() but when I want to reactive my video stream the image is frozen.

Here is the function I use to enable/disable video

```
const handleVideo = () => {
    setMuteVideo(!muteVideo);
    if (muteVideo) {
      createLocalVideoTrack().then((localVideoTrack) => {
        return room.localParticipant.publishTrack(localVideoTrack);
      });
      room.localParticipant.videoTracks.forEach((tracks) =>
        tracks.track.enable()
      );
    } else {
      room.localParticipant.videoTracks.forEach((tracks) =>
        tracks.track.disable()
      );
      room.localParticipant.videoTracks.forEach((tracks) =>
        tracks.track.detach()
      );
      room.localParticipant.videoTracks.forEach((tracks) =>
        tracks.track.stop()
      );
      const tracks = Array.from(room.localParticipant.videoTracks.values()).map(
        (publication) => publication.track
      );
      room.localParticipant.unpublishTracks(tracks);
    }
  };
```

Does anyone can help me to activate video stream properly please ?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't use Twilio but do you think doing a `detach()` and `unpublishTracks()` also possibly `stop()` is what causes a frozen image (_eg:_ last known frame before you ended the input)? What happens if you try: re-attach, re-enable, re-publish and restart instead of just one `enable()`...?

Answer (score 0):

I've made it with the very simple function restart() that is available on Twilio.
Thank you for your help VC.One